# A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property C#

Tags: c#

I need to get my list from one class to another. However I still get this error.

> " A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property"

I read that I have to get smth to constructor, however nothing works.

thanks in advance!

```
namespace NovejKalendar
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        Calendar c = new Calendar();
        Day d = new Day();
        c.AddRecord();
        c.Print();
        //Day d = new Day();            

        Console.ReadKey(true);           
    }
}

class Homework
{
    public DateTime dt;         
    public string subject;
    public string content;

    public Homework(DateTime dt, string subject, string content)
    {            
        String.Format("{0:d.m.yyyy HH:mm}", dt);
        //String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", dt); // "9.3.2008 16:05:07"
        this.dt = dt;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.content = content;
    }       
}

class Day
{
   List<Homework> hw = new List<Homework>();

   public List<Homework> GetList()
   {
      hw = new List<Homework>();
      return hw;
   } 
}

class Calendar
{
    //List<Homework> hw = new List<Homework>();

    Day d = new Day();
    List<Homework> hw = d.GetList();

    //List<Homework> hw = new List<Homework>();

    public void AddRecord()
    {            
        string a = "9.3.2008 16:05";
        string b = "19.12.2009 16:40";
        string c = "29.5.2005 16:55";
        hw.Add(new Homework(Convert.ToDateTime(a), "M", "ONE"));
        hw.Add(new Homework(Convert.ToDateTime(b), "F", "TWO"));
        hw.Add(new Homework(Convert.ToDateTime(c), "INF", "THREE"));            
    }

    public void PrintCollection<T>(IEnumerable<T> col)
    {
        foreach (var a in col)
            Console.WriteLine(hw);
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        foreach (var p in hw)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", p.dt, p.subject, p.content);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Here's a great page to help you understand the _right_ way to ask your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't initialize the field directly like this:

```
List<Homework> hw = d.GetList();
```

Instead just define the variable and initialize it in the class constructor.

```
class Calendar
{
    List<Homework> hw;

    public Calendar()
    {
       hw = d.GetList();
    }

    ...
}
```

The error message is clear about that..

> " A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method,
>   or property"

Comment: Thank you for that super speed reply! Still new in c# :)

Comment: No problem ;-) You can upvote/select the answer if that solved your question, so other people in the community can easily follow the advice when they find themselves facing a similar problem.